# get the value of a property from an http response object Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been searching but couldn't find yet an answer that would work for me on this.

I have a `http` post service, and I can get the 
answer in object format, my code goes like this:

```
data.subscribe(data => {
   let results;
   this.results = data;
   this.processResults(this.results);
}


processResults(obj: Object) {
   console.log(obj); 

  // what I want to do is retrieve the value in resultCodeConstant, I //tried functions like filter and find but always get an error, saying it's //does not exist on type Object
  // let item = obj.filter(element.name == 'resultCodeConstant')
}
```

my response from the http subscribe looks like this value of obj:

```
{
   authorizationToken: "qTYLf6f...", 
   secretQuestionId: null,
   secretQuestionSentence: null,
   resultCodeConstant: "AUTHORIZED",
   userAccountState: "active",
   …
}
```

How can I get a value in specific in this result ?
Do I need a loop ?

Comment: Change it from `obj: Object` to `obj: any`, and you should be able to get it like `obj.authorizationToken` for example, however `filter` is a function on arrays, so this still might not work how you want as your result is not an array

Comment: This has fixed it! Thank you so much, I lost hours on this, I clearly need to study the types again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My working solution:

```
this.http.get('https://localhost:44318/download/' + id)
    .subscribe(Response => {
        this.docD = Response;
        this.docList= this.docD.result[0].zawartoscPliku;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your obj should be of type any then you can access it as follows,

```
processResults(obj: any) {
  console.log(obj.authorizationToken); 
}
```